# CentOS 7: GNOME-Shell in multi-user.target / runlevel 3

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome-shell, cpu-usage

I have a server on which I have installed CentOS 7, Server with GUI. Now, I have set my server to boot to multi-user.target isolation level (or run level 3 in old speak). I am unable to understand why certain GNOME related processes are running in this mode! They are eating up CPU and it is bothering me. Here is a screenshot from my server, I'm logged in from my Windows machine using Cygwin.

```
# runlevel
N 3
# top
 1  [||                                                    2.0%]   Tasks: 125, 278 thr; 1 running
 2  [                                                      0.0%]   Load average: 0.38 0.29 0.32
 3  [                                                      0.0%]   Uptime: 01:37:40
 4  [|                                                     0.7%]
 Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||                     5.11G/15.3G]
 Swp[                                                  0K/32.0G]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 3317 dsadmin    20   0  518M  8720  6620 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.02 /usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server
 3580 dsadmin    20   0  518M  8720  6620 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server
 3342 dsadmin    20   0  518M  8720  6620 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server
 3341 dsadmin    20   0  518M  8720  6620 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server
 3319 dsadmin    20   0  518M  8720  6620 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server
 3206 dsadmin    20   0  380M  3480  2688 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11
 3215 dsadmin    20   0  380M  3480  2688 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11
 3214 dsadmin    20   0  380M  3480  2688 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11
 3210 dsadmin    20   0  380M  3480  2688 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11
 3207 dsadmin    20   0  380M  3480  2688 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11
 3166 dsadmin    20   0  126M  3424  2784 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
 3167 dsadmin    20   0  126M  3424  2784 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
 2914 dsadmin    20   0  561M  7684  5748 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.19 /bin/gnome-session --session=gnome-classic
 3487 dsadmin    20   0  596M 13988  9404 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.37 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
 3564 dsadmin    20   0  596M 13988  9404 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
 3562 dsadmin    20   0  596M 13988  9404 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.18 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
 3257 dsadmin    20   0 1740M  340M 44316 S  0.0  2.2  1:11.11 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
 3309 dsadmin    20   0 1740M  340M 44316 S  0.0  2.2  0:00.00 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
 3308 dsadmin    20   0 1740M  340M 44316 S  0.0  2.2  0:00.00 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

I would like to know how I can disable these processes, as I'm not planning to use a GUI so I don't see why these are running.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1)

Comment: got it. rookie mistake. will keep in mind

Comment: I have transcribed the contents of your screenshot for you, but you may want to check for errors in transcription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the process was being started by vnc server. after having disabled the vnc server, the processes are gone! saves me RAM